# Is it possible to make text in an HTML div tag fade to showing different text?

Tags: html, jquery, css

For example  is it possible to fade text from: "Hello world" to "Goodbye world" after a set duration of time?
I am new to javascript and css so I don't know where to start, I would really appreciate some help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to send another file.html to client if want to change some text.
For example you can use ejs and set your text as variable. In your js code you can choose what text you want send for client.
In ejs file: `<h2> <%- value %></h2>`, in js file `render.('filename.ejs',{value: 'sometext'})`

https://ejs.co/ for more info about ejs.